# Defining Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am currently stuck on a problem (this is not a homework problem) mainly because I am weak at DEFINING functions.

The problem states: Suppose $U$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ defined as $$U=\{(x,y,z) \ : \ x,y,z \in \Bbb R \ ; \  x+y+z=0\}.$$ Find a linear map other than the identity map defined from $U$ to $U$ such that $U$ is mapped to itself.

I tried to start with a basis (without knowing if it will work) and could not proceed any further. It would be helpful if you also please give the idea on how to define maps.

Thanks.

Comment: How about $f(x,y,z)=2(x,y,z)$?

Comment: The intuition of symmetry may serve in this case. The defining relation of $U$, which is $x+y+z=0$, is symmetric in $x,y,z$. One can then permute them to get a map. For example $(x,y,z)\mapsto (y,z,x)$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Both your functions, as it seems, follow the properties of linear transformations. Hence they are correct, as it seems to me. Indeed, the question did not carry many marks so I guess just defining any one of these linear maps would do.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $U$ is an hyperplane of $\Bbb R^3$ as it's a kernel of a linear form so $\dim U=2$ and we see that with $v_1=(1,-1,0)$ and $v_2=(1,0,-1)$ we have $(v_1,v_2)$ is a basis for $U$. Now we know that a linear transformation is entirely defined by giving the image of the vectors of a  basis so we may define the desired linear transformation $T$ by
$$T(v_1)=v_2\quad;\quad T(v_2)=v_1$$
and there are infinitely many other choices.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask how one can "determine" the elements in a basis? Suppose you are asked to find a basis of a given vector space. Is guessing the only way? (It is assumed you know the dimension of the space).

Comment: Indeed, I also found dim(U) = 2, so I had assumed two vectors to belong to that basis. But I did not know that the linear transformation is entirely defined by just knowing the images of the vectors in a basis. Suppose I try to prove this statement. How should I proceed? By assuming that if there exist two linear maps T and S with same images for same vectors in the basis, then T=S?

Comment: It suffices to find two linearly independent vectors in the subspace. We have $v_1\in U$ since its coordinates satisfy the condition $x+y+z=0$.

Comment: To prove the mentioned statement let $x$ an arbitrary vector and write it in the basis $(v_1,v_2)$. How we compute $T(x)$?

Comment: Sorry for the delay; there was a phone call.

Comment: So, $x=av_1+bv_2$. Then, $T(x)=aT(v_1)+bT(v_2)=av_2+bv_1=y$ where $y$ is an element of $U$.

Comment: Exactly and if we know $T(v_1)$ and $T(v_2)$ then we know $T(x)$.

Comment: Suppose that $T$ and $S$ are two linear transformations with same image for same vector in the basis. Then suppose we perform $T$ and $S$ on any arbitrary $x$ in $U$ and we will get the same $y$ in $U$ which is a unique linear combination of the vectors in the basis. Hence, $S=T$ for all $x$ in $U$. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome @AnonymousMaths

Answer (score 1):

Every linear transformation from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^3$ looks like this:
$$
f(x,y,z) = (a_{11}x + a_{12}y + a_{13}z,\,a_{21}x + a_{22}y + a_{23}z,\,
a_{31}x + a_{32}y + a_{33}z).
$$
In other words, you can define a linear transformation by choosing values for $a_{11}$, $a_{12}$, $\dots$, $a_{33}$. For example, all of the following functions are linear transformations:

- $f(x,y,z) = (x,y,z)$ (the identity transformation)
- $f(x,y,z) = (0,0,0)$ (the zero transformation)
- $f(x,y,z) = (z,x,y)$
- $f(x,z,y) = (x + 2y -z,-\pi x + \pi y + \pi z, 0)$

For your particular problem, you need to find a linear transformation that changes the $x$, $y$, and $z$ coordinates but does not change their sum.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know this. Now I shall try this method.

Answer (score 0):

**What about the negative identity, i.e. $\mathrm{f}(x,y,z) = (-x,-y,-z)$?**

**This is such that $\mathrm{f}(U) = U$.**

You can find the set of all linear maps as follows:

Your subspace has the equation $x+y+z=0$, i.e. $z=-x-y$. Every point is of the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{c} x \\ y \\ z \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c} x \\ y \\ -x-y \end{array}\right)=x\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{array}\right)+y\left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{array}\right)$$
It follows that $u=(1,0,-1)^{\top}$ and $v=(0,1,-1)^{\top}$ span $U$, in fact they form a basis for $U$. A general linear map $\mathrm{f} : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$, with respect to the usual basis, has a matrix representation
$${\bf F} := \left( \begin{array}{ccc} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{array}\right)$$
If you calculate ${\bf F}u$ and ${\bf F}v$ you can find conditions for ${\bf F}u \in U$ and ${\bf F}v \in U$. For example
$${\bf F}u = \left( \begin{array}{ccc} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{array}\right)\!\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c} a-c \\ d-f \\ g-i \end{array}\right)$$
For ${\bf F}u \in U$ you need $x+y+z=0$, i.e. $(a-c)+(d-f)+(g-i)=0$.
$${\bf F}v = \left( \begin{array}{ccc} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{array}\right)\!\left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c} b-c \\ e-f \\ h-i \end{array}\right)$$
For ${\bf F}v \in U$ you need $x+y+z=0$, i.e. $(b-c)+(e-f)+(h-i)=0$.
Solving both equations simultaneously gives, 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
h &=& a-b+d-e+g \\ \\
i &=& a-c+d-f+g
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Let ${\bf G}$ be the matrix given by substituting these solutions into ${\bf F}$. We have
$$\det({\bf G}) = (a+d+g)(ae-af+cd+bf-bd-ce)$$
If we allow $ae-af+cd+bf-bd-ce=0$, then ${\bf G}$ does not preserve $U$ as a plane. The kernel of ${\bf G}$ is contained within $U$. If $a+d+g=0$ then 
$$\ker{\bf G} \subset U \iff ae-af+cd+bf-bd-ce=0$$
Finally, we conclude that the set of linear maps with $\mathrm{f}(U) = U$ have matrices
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{array}\right)$$
for which the following conditions are met:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
a-c+d-f+g-i &=& 0 \\ \\
b-c+e-f+h-i &=& 0 \\ \\
ae-af+cd+bf-bd-ce &\neq& 0
\end{eqnarray*}$$
In the case $a+d+g=0$ we have $\mathrm{f}(\mathbb{R}^3) = U$.